# Catch 401 and render a message on the same component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

UPDATED:

I have a fetch wrapper to fetch my backend api's:

```
  export default function MainComponentWrapper({ url, children }) {

  const classes = useStyles()
  const [fetchError, setFetchError] = React.useState()
  const [data, setData] = React.useState()

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Bearer " + window.localStorage.getItem("access_token"),
      },
    })
      .then(resp => {
         return resp.json()
      })
      .then(fetchedData => {
        setData(fetchedData)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        setFetchError(error)
//          window.localStorage.removeItem("access_token")
//          window.location.replace("/")
      });
      if (fetchError) {
        return <div>Some error happened, show reload button</div>
}
  }, [url])
  if (data === undefined) {
    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <CircularProgress
         type="TailSpin" color="primary" size={25}
             />
      </div>
    )
  }
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      {React.cloneElement(children, { data: data })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

What I'am trying to do is when a 401 error is in the response, i want to render in the same component an error message and a button to return to the home page.

So far the only thing that i could do was in the if statement navigate to another page, but render something in the same page i can't.

My component:

```
export default function Audit({ data }) {

  const classes = useStyles()

    return (

    <div className={classes.root}>
      <h1>Audit logs</h1>
      <Table className={classes.table} size="small">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Date</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="left">action</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="left">user</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="left">detail</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {data && data.map(row => (
            <TableRow key={row.date}>
              <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                {row.date}
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell align="left">{row.action_type}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="left">{row.user}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="left">{row.action_parameters}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </div>
  )
}
```

[image]

Update:

What i could achieve was check what was inside data and if the message that i return is inside it i return a div like this:

```
 if (data === "No Permission")
        {
          return <ErrorHandler/>
        }
```

but this is not optimal and not what I wanted, I wanted to get the status code 401 and make an if with that

Comment: You just use another `useState` for error handling,

Comment: `if (fetchError)` that's correct, but don't place it in your `useEffect`.

Comment: I've tried put it before the other before the data === undefined and it's the same result

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** 401 is not caught as an error, you need to check it manually.

Use `setState` in the error handling part:

```
const [fetchError, setFetchError] = useState();

fetch(....)
.then(resp => {
  resp.status === 401 ? setFetchError(resp.status) : return resp.json();
})
.then(fetchedData => {
  setData(fetchedData)
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
  setFetchError(error);
});

if (fetchError) {
  return <div>Some error happened, show reload button</div>
}
```

This is just a barebones example, it might be better to handle the `status` logic more carefully.

As a sidenote, I don't think you need to clone the elements, but instead pass the `data` to the top component through a callback function, and let it pass individually to the children, or use React's `context`.

Comment: I tried to use your code, and got the same error 401. I'am not so good at react, I updated the question with the change that I made using your example.

Comment: That's because `data` is `undefined` (or null), and your `{children}` are trying to access. You need to do `data && data.map(.. => ....)` on the component that is not shown on your code.

Comment: I updated again, in the response comes a json message saying "no permission", so the data is not null

Comment: I think you're trying to do `data.map()` where data is not an array, even if it's not null.

Comment: ah well is not an array in this case, is just a string, but i don't want to map if i get the error, i want to render just a message. If there is no error then i want to map, but that was implemented already, now i am trying to implement just the error catch.

Comment: the problem is in the fetch error, if i console log it i get undefined, so there is no error being  catched

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I saw your updated version. I updated my answer. Basically, 401 is not thrown as an error, instead it goes as a valid response. You will need to do it manually:
`.then (...) if(response.status==401) { throw new Error(response.status)}`